# Loading a single data file containing multiple blocks of differing tab-delimited schemas

Tags: c#, etl

We are tasked with loading a file containing a number of different recordtypes and getting those records into a database (Sql Server at present, but need db agnostic for long run). Each block contains header and footers that include rowcounts and recordtype identifiers.

First, is there even a google-able term for that style of file?

I am considering first looping through the file to locate header records and record their location. Then with the knowledge of start and stop row numbers and record numers, loading that block. There will be considerable post-processing - normalization and key management, business logic.

These files will typically max at 600KB. I am thinking we could load all into memory but wondered if strategies already existed for loading this type of file.

*update*

Individual blocks contain tab-delimited records, each with their own schema.

Comment: Give an example of single record

Comment: I am not seeing that there is anything special about having multiple schemas in one file. There's no special name that I can determine.

It would appear that my best course of action is to parse the single file into smaller files first, then process the files individually using my etl framework of choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider using [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) - This is an open source library with excellent features for file processing. It works great with huge files and has many options for reading and processing CSV/TSV records.
I am not sure though, how it will work with different record schemas within the same file but it's definitely worth checking out

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm actually *more* concerned with the location of the record blocks and how best to process. I will take a look at the link.

Comment: I see that ayende uses FileHelpers from within rhino-etl. I will be using that once I get to that stage.

I _still_ need help in determining how best to import multiple schemas from within the same file, and what -- if anything -- that type of file is called.

Comment: I remember watching a screencast a while ago where the presenter showed how to integrate FileHelpers with Rhino-ETL. I can't find it right now, but maybe it's worth your time to google it. It was a very informative screencast. (If I do find find then I will post the link here)

Comment: HA! I see your rhino-etl comment. That's where I ended up heading, but with one large change.

It was actually easier to _split_ my file out because each block has headers AND footers. It would appear that FileHelpers doesn't specifically anticipate the row block headers and footers, and assumes that your various schemas might occur in multiple places throughout your file.

Parsing with FileHelpers was easy, and rhino-etl turned it into a workflow.